# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install mysql-workbench with mariadb 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have tried all the solutions that i found here but still facing the same problem 
i even purged everything and installed `mysql-server` and got the same error 
i tryed to install

`mysql-workbench.deb` from mysql website but the same error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3
                   Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

has anyone experienced this problem ?

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: same thing  now im getting `/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Which worked for you?